# Sending HTML mail through PHP - strange rendering

Tags: php, css, html-table, html-email, margin

I have a simple table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #444">E-mail</td>
    <td style="width:500px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #444">ex@ex.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #444">Message</td>
    <td style="width:500px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #444">sometext</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I test it, it looks fine:
[image]

When I send it through PHP mail() function, it looks like this:
[image]

**Why is that margin there?**

Just in case, my mail() headers are:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: do you have the same problem if you watch your mail with another mail-client? which one do you use?

Comment: I tested it in Gmail (screenshot) and one other client - same result

Comment: I hv checked above code in Gmail as well as in Outlook express. But couldn't replicate the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured it out - the problem was that I did `nl2br($message)` before sending. 
($message contains the above HTML code)

But thank you all for participation!

Answer (score 1):

The width of your table is 600px.

The width of the cells adds up as follows:

First cell: 1px border + 5px padding + 100px width + 5px padding + 1px border = 112px
Second cell 1px border + 5px padding + 500px width + 5px padding + 1px border = 512px

Total width: 624px in a 600px width table.

This may not be the problem, but I bet it is not helping.

I suggest you correct this first and then see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

did you by any chance insert \n\r between the rows in mail()?